# MongoDB: Typed expressions for nested arrays aren't working when using custom mapping

Tags: c#, mongodb, mongodb-.net-driver

I have following models:

```
public class Entity
{
    public ObjectId Id;
    
    private List<Item> _itemList;
    public virtual IReadOnlyList<Item> ItemList => _itemList.ToImmutableList();
}

public class Item
{
    public string ItemId;
    
    private List<string> _subItemList;
    public virtual IReadOnlyList<string> SubItemList => _subItemList.ToImmutableList();
}
```

In order to get the private members mapped, I setup following mapping:

```
public virtual BsonMemberMap MapList<TMember>(Expression<Func<TEntity, TMember>> memberListLambda)
    where TMember : IEnumerable
{
    var memberExpression = memberListLambda.Body as MemberExpression;
    var fieldName = $"_{memberExpression.Member.Name.ToCamelCase()}";
    return MapField(fieldName).SetIgnoreIfNull(true);
}
```

This mapping actually works well for basic Entity read/write operations but not for the `AddToSet` below:

```
var filter = Builders<Entity>.Filter;
var update = Builders<Entity>.Update;
Collection.UpdateManyAsync(
     filter.Eq(e => e.Id, id) & filter.ElemMatch(e => e.ItemList, Builders<Item>.Filter.Eq(i => i.ItemId, itemId)),
     update.AddToSet(e => e.ItemList[-1].SubItemList, subItemValue));
```

Error:

> Unable to determine the serialization information for e => e.ItemList

I am wondering if there is any elegant way to make it work?

Of course if I replace `e.ItemList` with `e._itemList` and make `_itemList` public and same for `_subItemList`, it works but would break the encapsulation.